# MySQL db query INNER JOIN and result in one column

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables Authors and Roles

Each Author has 3 roles columns in which I stored the ID from the table Roles.

What I'm trying to achieve is a a query that can retrieve the Authors and the name of the Role which is store in the table Roles.

```
Authors Table
ID | Name | Role1 | Role2 | Role3
1  | Leo  |   24  |  14   |  null
56 | Carl |   14  |  null |  null

Roles Table
ID | Name 
14 | Lawyer
24 | Scientist
```

What I'd like to achieve is

```
ID | Name | ROLES STRING
1  |  Leo | Scientist, Lawyer
56 |  Carl| Lawyer
```

The query that I have at this point is the following

```
SELECT authors.id, authors.name, GROUP_CONCAT(roles.name SEPARATOR ', ')
             from authors  
             INNER JOIN roles ON authors.role1 = roles.id OR authors.role2 = roles.id OR authors.role3 = roles.id
             WHERE authors.created_at > '". Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1440) ."' 
             ORDER BY authors.id DESC
```

But the result is not correct because the query retrieve only one record instead of the two expected (as shown below).

```
ID | Name | ROLES STRING
1  |  Leo | Scientist, Lawyer, Scientist
```

Any idea

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema. A database table is not a spreadsheet

Answer (score -1):

You need to group:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, GROUP_CONCAT(r.name SEPARATOR ', ') as author_roles
FROM authors a
iNNER JOIN roles r ON a.role1 = r.id 
                   OR a.role2 = r.id
                   OR a.role3 = r.id
WHERE a.created_at > '". Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1440) ."' 
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY a.id DESC
```